# Editing content of page having custom master page in office365 sharepoint site

Tags: development, asp.net

I have signed up for office 365, I'm trying to edit the sharepoint site in browser.

I have created a simple master page and a content page and uploaded to the site.

MasterPage.master

```
<%@Master language="C#"%>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"></SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/MasterPage.master" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" %>

<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<asp:Content ID="content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain">
My custom html
</asp:Content>
```

I get following error in browser:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
> Timestamp: Sun, 10 Jul 2011 05:34:53 UTC
>
>
> Message: 'null' is null or not an object
> Line: 2187
> Char: 9
> Code: 0
> URI: http://xxxxmysite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/wh/editor/js/default.aspx.js?rev=Wtx9sUy4auRcV8WoKmyYJQ%3D%3D&lcid=1033&

[image]

also the page displays only "please wait"
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think that your masterpage isn't complete, missing a lot of javascript references and a lot of contentplaceholders.

at http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/ and http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/odcSP14StarterMaster starter masterpages can be found. THey contain the minimum set of contentplaceholders, controls and javascripts that you need when developing your own masterpage.

edit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg447066.aspx describes how to create a custom solution to deploy your custom masterpage. It's a sandboxes solution, so it should fit in office365

Comment: I tried the starter masterpages but still I get the same message in browser,  I am new to sharepoint I just need a page with master page which will be editable through browser.

Comment: what about styling the existing masterpage using SharePoint Designer 2010? I believe it's a free tool.

Comment: Yea, it works with the SharePoint Designer 2010 but the user wants the functionality to edit the page on the fly

Comment: It is possible to edit web page from browser, right? I think I am missing something in the master pages...

Comment: I think you mean pagelayouts and publishing pages? This makes it possible to edit the content in browser, NOT style , NOT layout.

Comment: @NitinJS, that is what i said, you are missing a lot in this masterpage: required javascript, content placeholders and things like that ;). Try the following: set an out of the box masterpage as your masterpage. Check if you can modify content then.

Comment: yes, I want to add-edit content to the page @RubenHerman, May I request you to tell the missing things? I'm struggling to build the page as i am new to sharepoint @Bas Lijten

Comment: I would start like Bas Lijten from a "minimal" masterpage. Finding everything you're missing in the current will take you a lot of time...

Comment: but the minimal master page also is not editable in browser :(

Comment: NitinJS: you don't want to edit the masterpage in the browser ;). A masterpage is used for custom branding. You can edit the masterpage with SharePoint designer, if you want to. To edit content via the browser, you can use webparts or publishing pages. For info on custom branding (SP2007!!) check:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727372(v=office.12).aspx for